# False result SQL request in a code in PHP

Tags: php, sql

The SQL's request give three results in PHPMyAdmin and in my code give only one result.

The SQL request must extract three lessons (id,title,year) of school and the PHP script must show all lessons with a link in another page.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance

```
    <?php
$requete_cours="SELECT ID_COURS, COURS.SIGLE, ANNEE FROM COURS, MODULE WHERE COURS.ID_MODULE = MODULE.ID_MODULE AND ID_PERSONNE = $userid";
//echo $requete_cours;  
$res = mysqli_query($cxn, $requete_cours);
echo (mysqli_error ($cxn));
$tabLine = array();
while($ligne = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    echo '<a href="professeur_absences.php?classe=\''.$ligne['ANNEE'].'\'cours=\''.$ligne['SIGLE'].'\'>';
    echo $ligne['ANNEE'].' - '.$ligne['SIGLE'].'</a> <br/>';
    //$tabLien[$ligne['ID_COURS']] = $ligne['ANNEE'];

}
//var_dump($tabLien);
$_SESSION['tabLien'] = $tabLien;        
?
```

>

Comment: We probably can't answer this without knowing something about the data... Try adding `GROUP BY ID_COURS` to your SQL query (at the end)

Comment: A possibility also would be that the joining of the two tables is interpreted differently in sql than in php. did you try to state explicitely how the two tables whould be joined (like inner join, left join,...)?

Comment: @Thomas Why would the same query be interpreted differently? MySQL doesn't care where the query came from.

Comment: And it doesn't care whether you use an explicit or implicit join.

Comment: @Reeno If he adds `GROUP BY`, it will produce **fewer** rows. He's trying to get **more** rows.

Comment: Never had a problem with joining of tables. I will try this solution and report the result

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same `$userid` value when you test in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: 'GROUP BY' doesn't work in this case

Comment: @Barmar from what I remember from a case I saw once it was so that an sql command inside sql produced a different result as one done via php because the sqls were translated differently. Thus php had taken a different join back then than sql itself had when the command was used directly inside of sql (tbh that was quite some time ago and the newer php versions shouldn't have such a difference there)

Comment: @Barmar I assume ID_COURS is an unique ID. So a grouping by ID_COURS will undo any grouping and thus result in more rows.

Comment: @Thomas PHP doesn't do any interpretation of the query. It just sends it to MySQL, all the work is done there.

Comment: @Reeno There's no grouping in the query, so nothing to undo.

Comment: INNER JOIN is OK. Thanks for all!

Comment: Do you think a loop is false ? The SQL request is OK but the results shows thirteen times.